# Moment() format function adds extra minutes to date

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs, utc

I have a problem with Moment.js library. When I try to format a date it adds minutes to it.

I have tried using the .utc function but it also adds 4 minutes.

The same for the utcOffset(4).

```
moment('2019-04-06 13:00:00').format('HH:MM')
```

I want the above code to output 13:00

Comment: Your code is adding minutes because you are using 'MM' which is for month and current month is April (04) You should be using 'mm' which is for minutes.

Comment: Saw you mention that you've found solution to your problem based on the answers here. Please consider accepting one of the answers you found most helpful. Also I suggest you read this for before asking questions in the future: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 3):

use

```
moment('2019-04-06 13:00:00').format('HH:mm')
```

change MM to mm

checkout documentation for more units:

https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/

Answer (score 0):

Try this moment('2019-04-06 13:00:00').format('HH:mm')

Answer (score 0):

change it to, details [moment](https://momentjs.com/):

```
moment('2019-04-06 13:00:00').format('HH:mm')

"13:00"
```